# How to create a menu navigation on a Views page that uses contextual filters?

Tags: views, routes

I have a *projects* content type and I want there to be a menu for each project that would have *Project Overview*, *Project Details* & *Team Members*.

So in Views I created a page at `projects/` which would be the overview page that filters based on project title.

Then I have a page at `projects/%/details`, and another at `projects/%/people`.

So how would I either create a menu that I could put in the sidebar or somewhere that would work for any project, or maybe use tabs instead? Whichever is fine, but if you could teach me how to do both that would be cool.

I tried using the menu settings under *Page Settings* in Views, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Open the view where you had created the pages at **projects/%/details** or **projects/%/people**.

Under page settings where you had the path filled, add these additional settings to create a **Menu tab** or a **Contextual link**.

Go to **Menu** and select **Menu tab** as the type and fill in the title. If you want the link to be present as a contextual link, check the box which says context.

You can also set access permissions on who can see this tab depending upon the permission type you had selected.